# Method of meta-analysis of studies to determine mean blood level

Tags: variance, mean, meta-analysis

Generally meta-analysis is done to determine the efficacy of some treatment as compared to controls. Is it possible to do a meta-analysis of different studies for mean blood level of a chemical, its variance and its relation with age and gender. I have data from 10 different studies. For each study, I have data as follows:

```
Name of study
Number of subjects
Number of males
Mean age
Mean level of chemical in blood
SD of level of chemical in blood
```

What will be the best method to perform meta-analysis of all these studies? Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do a meta-analysis just with the means as your outcome measure. And since you also know the sample size and SD of the measurements within each study, it is easy to compute the sampling variances of the means. Then you can apply standard meta-analytic methods, using meta-regression to examine the relationship between the means and one or more moderator/predictors/covariates. Here is a simple example with simulated data. The data are simulated so that mean age is truly related to the means, while the proportion of males is not.

```
set.seed(12378)

dat <- data.frame(study = paste("Study", 1:10),
                  ni = round(runif(10, 30, 150)))
dat$prop.males <- round(round(runif(10, 30, dat$ni)) / dat$ni, 2)
dat$mean.age <- round(runif(10, 20, 60), 2)
dat$sdi <- round(15 * sqrt(rchisq(10, df = dat$ni - 1) / (dat$ni - 1)), 3)
dat$mi <- round(rnorm(10, 40 + dat$mean.age * .2, dat$sdi / sqrt(dat$ni)), 2)

library(metafor)

dat <- escalc(measure="MN", mi=mi, sdi=sdi, ni=ni, data=dat)

res <- rma(yi, vi, mods = ~ prop.males + mean.age, data=dat)
res
```

The output:

```
Mixed-Effects Model (k = 10; tau^2 estimator: REML)

tau^2 (estimated amount of residual heterogeneity):     0 (SE = 1.3717)
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):             0
I^2 (residual heterogeneity / unaccounted variability): 0.00%
H^2 (unaccounted variability / sampling variability):   1.00
R^2 (amount of heterogeneity accounted for):            100.00%

Test for Residual Heterogeneity: 
QE(df = 7) = 1.5660, p-val = 0.9799

Test of Moderators (coefficient(s) 2,3): 
QM(df = 2) = 12.2581, p-val = 0.0022

Model Results:

            estimate      se     zval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub     
intrcpt      41.2204  2.0664  19.9481  <.0001  37.1703  45.2704  ***
prop.males    0.1783  2.0095   0.0887  0.9293  -3.7601   4.1168     
mean.age      0.1521  0.0448   3.3918  0.0007   0.0642   0.2400  ***

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

We can also visualize these results:

```
wi   <- 1/sqrt(dat$vi)
size <- 0.5 + 1.2 * (wi - min(wi))/(max(wi) - min(wi))
plot(dat$mean.age, dat$mi, pch=19, cex=size, xlab="Mean Age", ylab="Observed Mean")

tmp <- predict(res, newmods = cbind(.5, 20:60))
lines(20:60, tmp$pred, lwd=2)
lines(20:60, tmp$ci.lb, lty="dashed")
lines(20:60, tmp$ci.ub, lty="dashed")
```

This yields:

[image: scatterplot]

The line indicates the estimated mean as a function of mean age for a group consisting of 50% males. The dashed lines are the corresponding 95% CIs.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer covering all aspects. I think to get a curve for males we can put 1 instead of 0.5 in "cbind(.5, 20:60)" and for females we can put 0 instead of 0.5 ?

Comment: What is the overall (all studies combined) mean and se of level, if we ignore age and gender?

Comment: As for your first question: Yes, use 1 for 100% males and 0 for 0% males. And to estimate the "overall" mean, you have two options: Ignore age and gender and just apply a random-effects model or, in my opinion, better: If it appears that age and/or gender are relevant predictors, then it makes no sense to speak of **the** overall mean, but you can always use the fitted model to compute an estimated mean for a particular combination of moderators values -- and those values could be the 'typical' mean age and proportion of males you see in your data.